# Minimizing a Qt application

Tags: qt, qt4

How can I minimize my application by clicking on some button in the application, on Windows Mobile and Symbian platforms, under Qt?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably [QWidget::setWindowState](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setWindowState) will suit you and the state for minimized is `Qt::WindowMinimized`.. So if your *base* widget is a `QMainWindow`, you can use this function on it.

It will work for desktop applications.. Should be similar for Mobile apps though..

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 9):

For a QWidget which is a [Window](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#isWindow) you can use the [`QWidget::showMinimized`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showMinimized) method.